# SSRS Chart add 2 legend entries

Tags: excel, reporting-services, charts

I hope someone here can help?

Please see the attached image. The top chart is what I am building in SSRS, the bottom was made in excel. The %Closed column in SSRS is a column that uses an expression to calculate the new and closed tickets column - is there any way to add an additional line to my chart as in the excel chart which shows the percentage closed? With a legend across the right of the chart like in the excel one?

Many thanks as always
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97T2w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is this: [Plot Data on a secondary axis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/plot-data-on-a-secondary-axis-report-builder-and-ssrs).

You will want to add the "% Closed" expression to the Values section of the chart, and then right click the new series in the Values section, go to Series Properties, go to Axes and Chart Area, and select Secondary Axis for the Vertical Axis.